# Do the words 'tied' and 'tight' have a common origin?

Tags: etymology, synonyms

I was reading a book in supposed 'Ye Olde English' and came across the sentence *'Perhaps she has him so tied he cannot get loose'*. This made me wonder if 'tied' and 'tight' have the same origin, in this sentence the meaning would be very similar if I swapped 'tied' for 'tight'.

Dictionary.com has this for the origin of 'tight'

*1400-50; late Middle English, sandhi variant of Middle English thight dense, solid, tight < Old Norse thēttr (cognate with Old English -thiht firm, solid, Dutch, German dicht tight, close, dense)*

And this for 'tie/tied'

*before 900; (noun) Middle English te (i) gh cord, rope, Old English tēagh, tēgh, cognate with Old Norse taug rope; (v.) Middle English tien, Old English tīgan, derivative of the noun; compare Old Norse teygja to draw.*

So this is just a coincidence or is there more to it?

Comment: Many online dictionaries will provide the etymology of words as well as their definitions. Have you tried looking them up in a dictionary? What did it say?

Comment: @Mari-LouA nothing there that would indicate a common origin.

Comment: +1 for sharing your research. It appears that the two words are unrelated, but maybe a user will post an answer explaining "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the *Oxford English Dictionary*, the *Concise Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology*, and the [Old English Translator](http://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/), *tie* comes to us from the Old English *tigan*, related to the Old Norse *taug* (rope) and *tegja (to draw, as in drag). *Tight* comes to us from the Old English *þíht*, related to the Old Norse *þehtr*, tightly woven.  So the two words descend to us from different Old English parents.

But the *OED* advises us to consider the obsolete word *tee*, meaning draw or drag, which comes to us from the Old English *teon* (past participle *togen*, related to the Old Norse *toginn*).  The parent of this word is a "primitive Aryan [i.e., Indo-European] word", which gave rise to the Latin *ducere* (to lead or draw) and to words of similar meaning in the family of Germanic languages.  Says the *OED*

> Derivatives of the same root survive in *taut*, *team*, ***tie***,
>   ***tight***, *tough*, *tow*, *tug*.

So the two are related if you go back far enough.

Comment: I wonder if the related word "tight" mentioned here might have a different etymology? The OED has several entries titled "tight." It distinguishes "The action of drawing, draught; going, marching, march, course, way" from OE tyht (cognate to "tee") and "Dense, as a wood or thicket" from Old Norse *þéhtr. It says of the latter "The change from thight to tight was perhaps due to the influence of native words from the *teuh , *tauh- , *tuh- verbal system." So it seems to indicate that the modern word "tight" is not originally related but has been remodeled after the words from PIE "dewk-."

Answer (score 1):

As an Addendum to deadrat's answer:

According to *The Families of Words* by Mario Pei (Harper Brothers, 1962), *tie* and *tight* both come from the PIE root *deuk, "to draw, pull".  The root on the Germanic side also gives us tow, tug, taut, team, tether, among many other words, including wanton and Herzog.  On the Latin side, we get duke, educate, and conduit, among many other words and some common suffixes (e.g., -ducive and -ductor).

So far, agreement.  But then Etymoline (which I had to check, darn it!) differs in the PIE roots of tie and tight.

*Tie*, From [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=t&p=20&allowed_in_frame=0)

> Old English teag, "cord, band, thong, fetter," literally "that with
>   which anything is tied," from Proto-Germanic *taugo (cognates: Old
>   Norse taug "tie," tygill "string"), from PIE *deuk- "to pull, to lead"
>   (cognates: Old English teon "to draw, pull, drag;" see duke (n.)).

*Tight* from [Etyomoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=t&p=21&allowed_in_frame=0)

c. 1400, tyght "dense, close, compact," from Middle English thight, from Old Norse þettr "watertight, close in texture, solid," and also from Old English -þiht ....., both from Proto-Germanic *thinhta- (cognates: Middle High German dihte "dense, thick," German dicht "dense, tight," Old High German gidigan, German gediegen "genuine, solid, worthy"), from PIE root *tenk "to become firm, curdle, thicken"

[Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=t&p=6&allowed_in_frame=0) agrees that taut, tow and tug come from the same PIE root as tie *deuk

It would be nice to have better than two out of three votes for the common PIE root of tie and tight.